# Displaying VTK in JavaFX

Tags: java, swing, javafx, java-8, vtk

Anyone has an idea if rendering VTK is already somehow possible in JavaFX?

I managed that in Swing using `vtkRenderWindowPanel` which can then be added to `JPanel`. But I still could not find a binding for JavaFX.

The option of displaying the VTK in Swing and then adding the Swing component in JavaFx using `SwingNode` also doesn't work for me (a green screen is displayed, nothing is rendered).

Any ideas and suggestions are very appreciated!!!

Comment: What you can do. Is look how they implementated the VTK into Swing and build you own implementation for JavaFX. 
Im not familiar with VTK that i can do it "fast" on my own.

Comment: Thanks Marcel. I am afraid VTK is too huge to reimplement it for JavaFx. In the meantime we decided to stick to Swing until JavaFx introduces multitouch support for Linux.

Comment: Look at the structure of vtk file. I once created a java swing program that read vtk files that displayed a 2D Mesh.